# A simple database inner join using django

Tags: python, django, orm

I have two tables from a legacy database imported to my django app using inspectdb

Here is my model definition

```
class AppCosts(models.Model):
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


class AppDefinitions(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
    permissions = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    appcost=models.OneToOneField(AppCosts, db_column='id')
```

Every app in AppDefinitions has one entry in AppCosts - a one to one relationship

When I use select_related() I get :

```
>>> AppDefinitions.objects.select_related().query.__str__()

    u'SELECT _app_definitions.id, _app_definitions.data,
  _app_definitions.permissions, _app_definitions.id, _app_costs.id, 
  _app_costs.cost FROM _app_definitions INNER JOIN _app_costs 
  ON ( _app_definitions.id = _app_costs.id )'

>>> a = AppDefinitions.objects.select_related().first()

>>> a.id
u'abaqus'

>>> a.cost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'AppDefinitions' object has no attribute 'cost'

>>> a.appcost
<AppCosts: abaqus,1.50>    

>>> a.appcost.cost
Decimal('1.50')
```

Now there are two problems :

- The query pulls in id twice from both fields (not a big deal because this table wont have more than a few hundred entries at most, but still, I want it to be right)
- I have to access cost as x.appcost.cost, rather than simply x.cost

How do I achieve this?

I would be loath to use custom SQL, because that would defeat the purpose of using django's ORM in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to use Django's ORM, but then say you want to do something diametrically opposed to that, ie accessing the cost as `x.cost`.

Django will not let you do that, since it completely breaks the object model. `cost` is an attribute on the AppCosts model, not the Costs one. If it's really bothering you, you *could* add a `property` on Costs which returns `self.appcosts.cost`, which will do what you want as long as you don't try to use it in queries.